# How do I return an index for each nvarchar col in a table?

Tags: t-sql

Imagine a simple table as follows

```
Create table test ( c1 nvarchar(10), c2 nvarchar(10), i1 int, c3 nvarchar(10) );
```

Is there a way I can query and get The index for the nvarchar columns?

The index would be 0 for c1 and 1 for c2 and 3 for c3 or if it is 1 and 2 and 4 respectively that is also ok

Comment: Just want clarify your question, do you mean to get list of columns (type=nvarchar) that are part of Index within a particular table? or to get all columns from a table that are **nvarchar**

Comment: The latter all columns of type nvarchar in actable with its column index I,e column number not sure how better to describe that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I guess something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ...
  AND TABLE_NAME = ...
  AND DATA_TYPE IN (...)
```